# SQL query that finds all the column, that is in multiple rows, but have different value in another column?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

If I have a "SALES" table, with columns of SaleID, Product#, and CustomerName.  and a PRODUCTS table with two columns product_ID and Name.  The contains 5 differnt products.  In the SALES table populates when a sale is made.

How would I query customer_name with only Product_ID of 1 and 2?

sales table

```
SALES_ID    PRODUCT_ID  CUSTOMER_NAME
1                    1      DAVE
2                    2      DAVE
3                    3      DAVE
4                    1      TOM
5                    2      TOM
6                    1      JANE
7                    1      MIKE
8                    1      MIKE
9                    3      MIKE
10                   4      MARY
```

I would like a table result to be

```
SALES_ID    PRODUCT_ID  CUSTOMER_NAME
1                   1       TOM
2                   2       TOM
```

Comment: You want a relational division. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/

Comment: update your question add  a proper (tabular) data sample and the expected  result  ..

Comment: Oracle and MySQL are two different product with different syntax. Which one do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Select s.CustomerName from SALES s 
 INNER JOIN PRODUCTS p ON s.Product#=p.Product# 
 WHERE p.Product# =1
 INTERSECT
 Select s.CustomerName from SALES s 
 INNER JOIN PRODUCTS p ON s.Product#=p.Product# 
 WHERE p.Product# =2
```